# If Cell empty then condition

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a problem with my code. It does not recognize the `Empty Cell`.

The condition is "If the cell is empty then repeat, else change the font of the text in the cell above the current cell"

```
Sub lastprice()
    Dim price As String
    Do
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find.Font
            .Size = 11
            .Bold = True
        End With
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "last price ("
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = True
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute

        If Selection.Find.Found = False Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            price = Trim(Selection.Text)

            If price <> "" Then ' I think there is some problem
                Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell, Count:=2
                Selection.Font.Name = "Cambria"
                Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
            Else
            End If
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

For more details check
[image]

It should elaborate more by second image of table with conditions

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the code in the debugger, which you should have done, and inspected what `price` was. It turns out it contains some kind of cell marker with character codes 13, 7. So an empty cell still in Word contains something. Change your if statement to the following:

```
If mid(price,1,1) <> Chr(13) Then
```

Comment: i have added second image to be more specific about loop

Answer (score 0):

After Edited: @paul ogilvie

```
 If mid(price,1,1) = Chr(13) Then
```

works for me, I change the logic `<>` to `=`

Here is working code

```
Sub lastprice()
Dim price As String
Do
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find.Font
    .Size = 11
    .Bold = True
End With
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "last price ("
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
If Selection.Find.Found = False Then
  Exit Do
  Else
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
   price = Trim(Selection.Text)
   If Mid(price, 1, 1) = Chr(13) Then
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell, Count:=2
    Selection.Font.Name = "Cambria"
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
   Else
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
   End If
   End If
Loop
End Sub
```